# How to move value of any column starting with the second to a new line?

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I am using PowerShell for this task and would like to move the value of any column starting with the 2nd to their own line. I have a CSV file with something like this:

```
red,blue,yellow
red
red,blue
```

I want to achieve the following

```
red
blue
yellow
red
red
blue
```

I don't know how many possible columns I would have in any given CSV file, but the end result is all values in each column on their own line.

I was thinking of using the `Import-Csv` cmdlet with `Select-Object` but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Well, the example you have posted is not a valid CSV file so Import-CSV probably is not a good option.

Comment: Are all of the line comma delimited?

Comment: Good point! The one lines are not comma delimited, but I can add a comma at the end of each line if that makes it easier...

Comment: Could you show an actual example of the structure of an actual file then?

Comment: same as above, but replace colors with names... i just grabbed the first  3 lines of the file; none of the lines end with commas

Comment: So the items in each line ***are*** comma delimited. Then the answer I gave should work as is.

Comment: Ok cool, I thought you needed a comma for them to be comma delimited, even for the ones that have only one color... it worked though, so thx again!

Answer (score 3):

With the example data that you have currently shown, then:

```
$out = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
Get-Content C:\Path\To\InputFile.txt | %{$out.AddRange(($_ -split ','))}
$out | Set-Content C:\Path\To\OutputFile.txt
```

I habitually put together lists because I almost always plan to process the list in some way. In this case if you simply want a new file the list is not needed:

```
(Get-Content input.txt) -split ',' | Set-Content output.txt
```

Comment: `(Get-Content input.txt) -split ',' | Set-Content output.txt` should suffice.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I do tend to be overly explicit at times. I started my career maintaining other people's crappy code so I am often overly verbose in my crappy code. :)